# Adding the date to the CLOSED tag in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have started using emacs org-mode recently to maintain my TODO lists. I have used it before a long time back. Back then, I was able to automatically add a date whenever moving a task from **TODO** to **DONE** tag adding a *CLOSED:*  sub-label to the DONE label.

However, I forgot how to do that. Can anyone help tell me how to add the CLOSED tag. in org-mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the following variable  (See the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Closing-items.html) for more info and further customization if desired).

```
(setq org-log-done 'time)
```